# How can I throttle certain player actions?

Tags: input, events, timing

#### Background

I have a variable time step, component based game, with components that collectively hold an entity's properties and different systems that act on entities with certain required components.

The player controls a ship that can fire bullets. I have an input system that works on entities with a `PlayerControlComponent` (nothing more specific yet) and creates an entity every frame if a key is held down.

---

#### Question

How should I manage limiting or throttling this so that it can't occur closer than 1 second apart in a reusable way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe I'm missing the point because it seems so simple but isn't something like this enough?

```cs
public class Component
{
    protected limit = 1.0f;
    private float timer = 0.0f;

    public virtual void Update(float dt)
    {
        timer += dt;
        if(timer >= limit)
        {
            timer -= limit;
            LimitedUpdate();
        }
    }

    public virtual void LimitedUpdate() {}
}
```

And then you override `LimitedUpdate` and put anything that you only want triggering from `limit` to `limit` seconds there.

**Edit**

And to fulfill the idea on your comment about making it into a centralized component and event driven (instead of polling driven):

```cs
public class ActionManager
{
    private struct ActionEntry
    {
        public Action Action;
        public float Limit;
        public float Timer;
    }

    private Dictionary<string, ActionEntry> entries = new Dictionary<string, ActionEntry>();

    public RegisterAction(string id, Action action, float limit = 1.0f)
    {
        // Note: I made Timer = limit so that the first call is 'free'
        entries[id] = new ActionEntry { Action = action, Limit = limit, Timer = limit };
    }

    public void TryAction(string id)
    {
        if(entries[id].Timer >= entries[id].Limit)
        {
            entries[id].Action();
            entries[id].Timer = 0.0f;
        }
    }

    public void Update(float dt)
    {
        foreach(var entry in entries)
        {
            entry.Value.Timer += dt;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Something like that would probably work (with changes though, I only want it triggered by an event, not every 1 second). I was wondering if I could create a single system/object that could manage deciding whether to perform different actions or not, rather than managing the creation of your object for each possible action.

Comment: So you might `RegisterAnAction` specifying a GUID and rate limit, then whenever you wanted to do your action you might call `TryDoAction` which would either do the action, or not, depending on when the action was last performed. (Or maybe you'd call `CanDoAction` and perform the action outside the rate management object).

Comment: Simple enough, give me three minutes.